# Отображение ADB устройства в Android Studio

Tags: linux, android-studio, adb

Пытаюсь включить отладку с подключенного по adb устройства Redmi Note 11S в Android Studio, все бы идеально, но оно почему-то отображается в овале. Куда копать?
[image: Овал]